# How to properly persist props between functional components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have one functional component named 'Shop', which decides which apidatabase to use depending on the type of shop (e.g shopAPI_1, shopAPI_2, etc) as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shopname === 'shopName_1') {
      setSelectedAPI('shopApiName_1');
    } else if (shopname === 'shopName_2') {
      setSelectedAPI('shopApiName_2');
    } else if (shopname === 'shopName_3') {
      setSelectedAPI('shopApiName_3');
    } else {
      setSelectedAPI('null');
    }
  }, [shopname]);
```

Then, through `react-router-dom` I send this `selectedAPI`to another functional component as follows:

```
  <div>
      <Link to='/'>BACK</Link>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.title}>Search your product at {shopname}</div>
        <div className={styles.searchBar}>
          <SearchBar apidatabase={selectedAPI} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This SearchBar component renders a set products, which can be clicked upon and guide you to aother page, which shows data related to the product as follows:

```
        productData
          .filter((item) => !selectedCategory || item.Category === selectedCategory)
          .map((item) => (
            <Link
                className={styles.searchBarLink}
                to={`/metrics/${item.id}`}
                state={{ itemData: item }}
                key={item.id}
              >
              <ProductBox
                name={item.Name}
                price={item.Price}
              />
            </Link>
```

**Issue:**
At first try, this works as expected, but when I access the product's metrics page and then return back to the product listing page, the `selectedAPI` sent as a prop is lost and set to `null`.

*Although I am pretty sure that there are better implementations to this approach*, **I would like to know how to persist the selected API when I return from the metrics page into the product listing page.**

The only workaround for this bug that I found, is to go back to the shop selection menu and search the product again.

**Notes to understand the issue that I am facing**

- For the backend I am using Supabase and doing SQL queries to the database
- Every shop has its own database, thus the need for different 'databaseapi'.

EDIT (Added a minimal reproducible example):

The Shop function takes from the URL: http://IP:3000/shop/shopName_1 the `shopName_1` which is then evaluated and used to select the correct API to use.

```
function Shop() {
  // Access the shopname parameter using useParams
  const { shopname } = useParams();
  const [selectedAPI, setSelectedAPI] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shopname === 'shopName_1') {
      setSelectedAPI('shopApiName_1');
    } else if (shopname === 'shopName_2') {
      setSelectedAPI('shopApiName_2');
    } else if (shopname === 'shopName_3') {
      setSelectedAPI('shopApiName_3');
    } else {
      setSelectedAPI('null');
    }
  }, [shopname]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to='/'>BACK</Link>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.title}>Search your product at {shopname}</div>
        <div className={styles.searchBar}>
          <SearchBar apidatabase={selectedAPI} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you may observe, I am using passing this information down to another component named `SearchBar` as props with the name `apidatabase`. As you may observe below, this apidatabase value is used for fetching data from a backendservice (this works correctly) and the output from this backend service is then shown to the user in a `ProductBox` which is wrapped by a `Link` that routes the user to a metrics page of that specific product.

```
export default function SearchBar( {apidatabase} ) {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('');
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const error = false;

  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchCategories() {
      try {
        const productCategories = await backendService.getCategories();
        setCategories(productCategories)
      } catch (error) {
        //TODO: Add better error handling
      }
    }

    fetchCategories();
  }, [])

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    
    
    setSearchInput(inputValue);
    setLoading(true);
      
      try {
        const output = await backendService.findProductByName(inputValue, apidatabase);
        setProductData(output);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        //setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
        

   const handleSelectedCategory = (e) => {
    if (e.Category === selectedCategory) {
      setSelectedCategory(''); // Set to an empty string to reset the filterx
    } else {
      setSelectedCategory(e.Category); // Update the selected category
    }    
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.searchInput}>
        {searchInput}<br/>
        {/*selectedAPI*/}
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name of the product"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={searchInput}
        />
        <div className={styles.filterTitle}>
            Filter results by: {selectedCategory}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.searchFilter}>
          <div className={styles.buttonWrapper}>
             {categories.map((item, index) => (
                <button 
                  id={`categoryButton${index}`}
                  key={item.id}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedCategory(item)}
                  className={styles.button}>{item.Category}</button>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.productWrapper}>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <p>Error: {error}</p>
      ) : (
        productData
          .filter((item) => !selectedCategory || item.Category === selectedCategory)
          .map((item) => (
            <Link
                className={styles.searchBarLink}
                to={`/metrics/${item.id}`}
                state={{ itemData: item }}
                key={item.id}
              >
              <ProductBox
                name={item.Name}
                price={item.Price}
              />
            </Link>
        ))
      )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  
}
```

**How to reproduce this issue?**

Inside the `SearchBar` function, route to another page, such as /metrics, and then go back to the previous functional component. You may observe that the apidatabase value is lost.

In order to go back to the previous page (functional component) I use a Link from `react-router-dom` pointing to the `SearchBar` function.

EDIT 2: I added the routing section of the code if it helps throubleshoot this issue further

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/shop/:shopname' element={<Shop />} />
            <Route path='/metrics/:id' element={<ProductMetrics />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
      {/*<Footer/>*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When does `shopname` change to a value that isn't one of `"shopName_1"`, `"shopName_2"`, or `"shopName_3"`? Based on the code you have provided, when this happens is when the `shopname` state is set to `null`. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] so we can see what all the code is doing, and when it is doing it? Please also clarify the reproduction steps and include all relevant routing/navigation code.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, thank you for taking interest and time in my question. I have edited it by providing you with a snippet of code that should provide you with more information to assist me. I will be looking forward to your response.

Comment: Well, if you navigate to `"/shop/:shopname"` with anything other than 1 of those 3 path param values the state will be set to null. What does "link pointing to `SearchBar` function" mean? A user is navigating from some `"/metrics/:id"` route path back to *what* exactly?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your response. When the user clicks on the productbox it gets routed to this `IP:3000/metrics/productName` and when it presses the `BACK` button/link, it should get routed back to http://IP:3000/shop/shopName_1, but I just observed that it does not change the route in the browser... not sure how to address this at the current moment.  

The `apidatabase` value when returning is `null`

Comment: This is the `BACK` button observed from the ProductMetrics function `<Link to="/shop/shop_name1">BACK</Link>`

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your app code that reproduces the routing/state issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried to use your codesandbox suggestion, please find the link here https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wescoff-yx7627?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I had to default export the `App` component to get the sandbox running. I can't reproduce the null shopname issue though. The shops' "BACK" button navigates to `"/"` which renders `Home` which renders the 3 shop buttons, and upon clicking any one of those correctly navigates to the shop page. How would I get the UI to navigate to a metrics page? I do see in the `ProductMetrics` component this link `<Link to="/shop/lidl">BACK</Link>` which ***would*** navigate to a shop page that doesn't exist and set the `shopname` state to `null`.

Comment: I have to say that I am still learning the React framework and I although I am trying my best with the sandbox, I do not understand how you have fixed the 'default export'

Comment: Ok I read the docs and understood the assigment (too many hours, I need a rest)

Comment: @DrewReese Ok, I was able to succesfully reproduce my issue in the sandbox. Please follow this steps:   1. Select any shop; 2. You will observe the `apidatabase` 3. Click on the product box 4. In the metricd page, click on BACK 5. apidatabase will be seen as `null`

Comment: Have you made any updates to the sandbox? I still have to fix the `App` component export to get the code to run. What exactly am I observing in step 2 "You will observe the `apidatabase`"? There's nothing to click on for step 3, there exists only the search title and input box. And like I said previously, if from any page you navigate to `"/shop/lidl"` then obviously the `shopname` state will be updated to `null` since `"lidl"` isn't one of those three shop names.

Comment: I did not save the changes previously, please find here the new link https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wescoff-yx7627?file=/src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `SearchBar` component that renders the links to the product metrics pages doesn't share any routing paths with the `ProductMetrics` component my suggestion would be to forward the current shop page as a referrer location that the "BACK" link in `ProductMetrics` can navigate back to. Pass the current location in link state to the `"/metrics/:id"` route.

SearchBar

Access and forward the current location in route state.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function SearchBar({ apidatabase }) {
  const location = useLocation(); // <-- location

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <div className={styles.productWrapper}>
        <Link
          className={styles.searchBarLink}
          to={`/metrics/${42}`}
          state={{
            itemData: item,
            from: location // <-- pass location in state
          }}
          key={42}
        >
          <ProductBox name={"prodName"} price={42} />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ProductMetrics

Access any passed route state and attempt to navigate back to the previous location, e.g. `state.from`, otherwise navigate to the home page.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ProductMetrics() {
  const { state } = useLocation(); // <-- access route state
  
  ...

  return (
    <div align="center">
      ...
      <div>
        <Link to={state?.from ?? "/"}> // <-- navigate to previous page or home
          BACK
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```